# Debian : Permission to write to directories and files

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, file-permissions, debian-jessie

I just installed a [October CMS](http://octobercms.com) installer. This installer requires a **Permission to write to directories and files**. After a search on Google, I didn't find out how to make this. How can I make this? On Apache2, Debian8 and in the folder `/var/www/html/`.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean [step 4](http://octobercms.com/docs/help/installation) : `Grant writing permissions on the installation directory and all its subdirectories and files.` ?

Comment: @user2196728 exact. However, Tomasz Klim have answer my question.

Comment: @user2196728 Yes, but the effect seem to go away after a bit. That's weird, but I delete again my files, and reinstall October, and `Permission to write to directories and files` was an `X` again... _I can make the `chown` command again, and it's work._

Comment: Do you mean that permissions does not persists ?

Comment: @user2196728 Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute as root:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/
chmod -R u+w /var/www/html/
```

After, reload Apache2 (as root):

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work. Please review my edit, it could help others.

Comment: Restarting Apache is not necessary.

Comment: In my machine, yes, otherwise, it will not be applied.